# Chrome Extension to extract specific ElementID

Tags: dom, google-chrome-extension, webbrowser-control, getelementbyid, browser-automation

I am looking for a chrome extension to extract the inner text value of a specific ElementID everytime the DOM is refreshed of a specific page.

I would like this value to be written to a text file on a generic local directory. (ie C:\UsersUserName\whatever) Ideally this would overwrite the value each time it loads in the text file.

So for example. if I navigate to a specific page.. lets say Google.com I would like the extension to look for the elementclass "gN089b" and extract the words "Google Search" to a text file. (I am using the example of a class, but the one i need is an ID -- just wanted to give a super generic example)

Alternatively an extension is not required, if there was a way to do this in a background running VBS script or something I am open to anything that works :)
Any help and direction here would be lovely!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please post whatever code you've written so far.

Comment: You state you are looking for an extension, something like this should be easy to produce on your own as something specific to what you want just may not be available.  I could see you doing this with a chrome-extension.  

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uh84Asy2W4s watch the video to give you a good start on making extensions.

From there, I would write it so that it...

1)  Checks window.location to verify the current webpage
2)  If said webpage equals google.com, document.getElementByID('gN089b')

Shouldn't be that difficult...  But watch the video, get started, help is out here.